# Why this UserControl can't fill the TreeViewItem.Header?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

[image]

As shown above, the TreeViewItem.Header width is fill to the parent.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFvZs.png)

but its child the "Bd[Border]" is too small. Why it don't fill the parent default.

[image]

What should I do? I want the UserControl "TaskHeader" fill to the TreeViewItem.Header.

The UserControl Code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETvJf.png)

I post the project in [GitHub](https://github.com/Xnco/WPF_Nodes). Project in `PastNodes` folder.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post images because need at least 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is the `TreeViewItem`'s control template has the `Header` content placed in a `Grid.Column` with a `Width="Auto"`.

Here are a couple options:

1. Extract the control template for the `TreeViewItem` and edit it to fit your needs.
2. Set a Width on the TaskHeader like so: `Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}"` - this is a bit of a hack, but works.

Comment: Thank u, I try set to "Stretch" for "HorizontalAlignment" and "HorizontalContentAlignment", Nothing has changed.

Comment: I updated the solution with the exact cause of the problem and a couple options.

Comment: I try to option 2, the result is TaskHeader's width is Unlimited. Now I'm trying option 1. Thank you for comment.